# How do I open the gates in Yaga Shura's Lair?

Tags: baldurs-gate-2, baldurs-gate-2-throne-of-bhaal

I'm in the Yaga Shura's Lair, and there's a big door which I can't open, it says I'm not strong enough (but my strength is 21!). I killed all the mobs in the area, there doesn't seem to be much else I can do.

How do I open the gates in Yaga Shura's Lair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reference I can find is in [the planet Baldurs Gate walkthrough](http://www.planetbaldursgate.com/bg2/tobpg/8_6.shtml), this walkthrough unfortunately does not say how much STR is needed, but does say it only cares about strength.

Might wanna get a STR potion and try again.

Comment: Ok I got it, this being a Fire Giant lair, you need *Fire Giant strength*, which is 22.